# Swift - table view delegate methods not getting called from view controller class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, delegates

I have a `UITableView` placed on a view controller in storyboard. I set the `datasource` and `delegate` for the table view to `self` and I specified the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` in the view controller class declaration. All of the datasource functions work properly. In other words, when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, it executes fine.

The problem is that the delegate methods for the `tableView` are not executing. I verified this by placing a breakpoint at the beginning of

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

I also noticed that the keyword `optional` is specified to be prefixed for the above delegate method as such:

```
optional func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

However, if I add the `optional` keyword to the beginning of the function, I get the error `optional can only be applied to protocol members`.

I have no idea why my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is not getting called. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure that you linked your tableview in Storyboard?

Comment: I think I've got it fixed. I deleted where the delegate and datasource was created in IB. Then I restarted Xcode and re-created the delegate and datasource. That seems to have resolved it. I'm guessing something was corrupt perhaps. Thank you for the response.